# Automatically "taxing" native token transactions

Tags: smart-contract, token

To fund the "commons" for some community with some token T, it might make sense to "tax" transactions within this community, similarly to how a gas fee funds the operations of the underlying blockchain, or how a town raises money for the fire department through a sales tax on retail transactions.

The idea is that if A sends 100 T tokens to B, say 1 of those gets sent to C (the commons) and only 99 arrive with B. I would want this to be automated, so that within that community, nobody can cheat.

Can I do this with a native token? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I know that royalties can be set for NFT projects. I haven't yet seen royalties set for fungible tokens, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. What you're proposing sounds like a 1% royalty.  You may find some good information here: https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/116/files

Comment: Ah, excellent, the ground work seems to come into existence then.